# How to enable wifi without confirm on android 7.0

Tags: android, ionic-framework, runtime-permissions

I just use wifiwizard to enable WLAN in ionic app.
I have give the app all the permission in the system settings.
Android 5.0 can work without the Pop-ups, but 7.0 always need confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 5.0 is based on the older install time permission model, while android 7.0 has run time permission system. This means that on Android 7.0  the permissions to apps are not granted at install time, but rather are requested on the fly during the time when the resource is required to be used.

Read more about it here :  [Android runtime permission system.](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en)